# How do I initialize the variable?

Tags: java, variables

I'm writing a program for my class where I have to use a for loop to takes two numbers from the keyboard.  The program should then raise the first number to the power of the second number.  Use a for loop to do the calculation. I'm getting the error that inum3 is not being initialized (I understand because the loop may never enter) but I cannot figure out how to make this work. Line 25 and 28 to be specific.

```
import javax.swing.*;


  public class Loop2
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {


    int inum1, inum2, inum3, count;
    String str;

    str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter a Numer");
    inum1 = Integer.parseInt(str);

    str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter a Numer");
    inum2 = Integer.parseInt(str);


    for (count = 1; count == inum2; count+=1)
    {
     inum3 = inum3 * inum1;
    }

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format ("%s to the power of %s = %s", inum1,inum2, inum3), "The Odd numbers up to" + inum1,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}//main
  }// public
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to initialize the variable `inum3`.  As it stands right now, when your program tries to execute

`inum3 = inum3 * inum1;`

`inum3` has no value, so it can't do the multiplication.

I think you want it to be 1 in this case.

So instead of

`int inum1, inum2, inum3, count;`

you can do

`int inum1, inum2, inum3 = 1, count;`

Comment: I changed the value of inum3 in my declarations, the problem I am having now is that the Joptionpane that displays at the bottom of the code is displaying a "1" where I want the new value set inside the loop to display.

Comment: If I move that Pane into the for loop, it does not display at all.

Comment: add a println to make sure that inum3 is correct after the loop completes.  You definitely dont want the pane to be in the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the timely responses Hvgotcodes. The print line is displaying a "1" as well. So does that mean the math is not being executed inside the loop?

Comment: right,  that's what it means.  it only makes sense if you put inum1 as 1.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to properly execute this program?

Comment: count <= inum2, not == -- your condition is never true so the loop never executes

Comment: This did not solve my issue, I'm basically trying to take in 2 numbers, taking the first number and raising it by the second without using math.pow and I must use a for loop. Ive been at this for about 3 hours now If I could get a bit more help I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

initialize num3 to one because you cand use something to define itself.

num3 = one;

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Loop2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int base, exp, result = 1;
        String str;

        str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter a Number");
        base = Integer.parseInt(str);

        str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter an Exponent");
        exp = Integer.parseInt(str);

        for (int count = 0; count < exp; count++) {
            result *= base;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("%s to the power of %s = %s", base, exp, result),
                "The Odd numbers up to" + base, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I now understand what I was supposed to be doing!